# onChange function in customInput from material ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using a template that build on material ui. I try to put onChange in this code but it doesnt work. I also try to add onChange in customInput too but still doesnt work. I am think to put onChang inside inputProps but I have no idea how to put function in object.

```
handleChange = e => {
    const {name, value} = e.currentTarget;
    this.setState({[name]: value});
};
......
<CustomInput
                             labelText="Username"
                             id="username"
                             name='username'
                             **onChange = {e =>this.handleChange(e)}
                             formControlProps={{
                               fullWidth: true
                             }}
                             inputProps={{                              
                              value: `${this.state.user.username}`, 
                            }}
                           />
```

How can I fix this problem?Thanks

Comment: remove ```**``` before ```onChange```
also do you receive ```const {name, value}```?

Comment: post the example of the question with modification in this  template: https://codesandbox.io/s/49t79 and repost new url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sample on how to use `onChange`:

```
<CustomInput
    id="pass"
    formControlProps={{
        fullWidth: true
    }}
    inputProps={{
        onChange: (event) => this.handleChange(event),
        placeholder: "Password",
        type: "password"
    }}
 />
```

[Here](https://github.com/creativetimofficial/material-kit-react/issues/6) is the source of the sample, as well as a discussion on how to use the onChange event.

Finally, assuming that all the rest of your code works, this is (kind of) what you need:

```
handleChange = e => {
    const {name, value} = e.currentTarget;
    this.setState({[name]: value});
};
......
<CustomInput
    labelText="Username"
    id="username"
    name='username'
    formControlProps={{
        fullWidth: true
    }}
    inputProps={{   
        onChange: (e) => this.handleChange(e),                           
        defaultValue: `${this.state.user.username}`
    }}
/>
```

Comment: I try and it doesnt work at first, but it does when I change value to defaultValue. Here is my final code
<CustomInput
                             inputProps={{                              
                              defaultValue:`${this.state.user.username}`,
                              name:"username",
                              onChange: (e) => this.handleChange(e),
                            }}
                           />

Comment: Great! Thanks :)